# Merge links on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, hyperlink, analytics

I have started a Fb campaigns and I need to track the clicks on link on Google Analytics.

The problem I have is that the page link came on GA with different expressions after the normal URL, so they are collected in different rows instead of in a single one.

I will make you an example.
I need to track this link:

/es/el-folleto-de-los-vinos-italianos-con-denominacion-de-origen-2020

But everytime a person is clicking on it from Fb ads, the link appears in a different way on GA, such as:

/es/el-folleto-de-los-vinos-italianos-con-denominacion-de-origen-2020/?fbclid=IwAR2Uc9rSNA7RxYU4wdSrtJrvpVS8SS6TrsMD7KEXOmJm7-PczRtN2CV2UUQ

or

/es/el-folleto-de-los-vinos-italianos-con-denominacion-de-origen-2020/?fbclid=IwAR0OIQhQ-szHlm5BcSQU14UPMIri8HSSV4ws2uowtlvuW8qI7AQA_RWB0jU

Result?

I have 6000 rows for clicks on the same page.

How can I merge all those links (that create different rows) in only one row that is for all the clicks referring to the same page?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If they have been collected in this way in Analytics you can no longer merge them.

However you can filter by the page path and see the result in the **first row** which represents the aggregate summary of all the individual offending pages.

Also, from the `View settings` you can exclude the `fbclid` parameter so that Analytics excludes it from the URLs and in the next reports (from then on) you will see the pages all together on the same row.